# ubuntu getting stuck during boot

Tags: dual-boot

Recently I am facing a great trouble .
My Laptop : HP Probook 440 G3 Core i5 6th Gen 1TB HDD 4GB RAM 14" laptop
I installed  Ubuntu 18.04 ,19.04 or 19.10 a lot of time (dual boot). I can go with the distro easily 1 or 2 days minimum.Then when I am gonna boot then after sometime it always stuck with pre-log in mode picture with ubuntu sign. I don't  understand what to do.
I am really very eager to learn about Linux OS .
Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Is there any message displayed when pressing the "right arrow" on the keyboard while on the screen?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it works for you, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`. Then reboot.